# how do you use target data-validator in azure databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, validation, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to run the data validation framework called data-validator created by Target to validate data from a parquet file in Azure databricks.

I have created a spark job that will use the data-validator fat jar file.

If I give a parameter --help, I can get the help regarding how to use data-validator, but when I pass the --config test_config.yaml file, the data-validator can't find the file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ2p1.png)

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: libraryDownload.sleepIntervalSeconds
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: libraryDownload.timeoutSeconds
Warning: Ignoring non-Spark config property: eventLog.rolloverIntervalSeconds
21/12/30 06:17:29 INFO Main$: Logging configured!
21/12/30 06:17:29 INFO Main$: Data Validator
21/12/30 06:17:30 INFO ConfigParser$: Parsing `dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/jyoti/test_config.yaml`
21/12/30 06:17:30 INFO ConfigParser$: Attempting to load `dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/jyoti/test_config.yaml` from file system
21/12/30 06:17:30 ERROR Main$: Failed to parse config file 'dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/jyoti/test_config.yaml, {}
DecodingFailure(java.io.FileNotFoundException: dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/jyoti/test_config.yaml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:94)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:79)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:57)
    at com.target.data_validator.ConfigParser$.com$target$data_validator$ConfigParser$$loadFromFile(ConfigParser.scala:39)
    at com.target.data_validator.ConfigParser$$anonfun$6.apply(ConfigParser.scala:57)
    at com.target.data_validator.ConfigParser$$anonfun$6.apply(ConfigParser.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.target.data_validator.ConfigParser$.parseFile(ConfigParser.scala:53)
    at com.target.data_validator.Main$.loadConfigRun(Main.scala:23)
    at com.target.data_validator.Main$.main(Main.scala:171)
    at com.target.data_validator.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
, List())
21/12/30 06:17:30 ERROR Main$: data-validator failed!
```

I had stored the yaml file in the dbfs.

Please let me know how to pass the YAML config file in data-validator using the spark-job in databricks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass file name formatted accordingly to [DBFS Local File API](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis) because `ConfigParser` library most probably only works with local file.  To do that you need to replace `dbfs:` with `/dbfs`, like in your example - change `dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/jyoti/test_config.yaml` to `/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/jyoti/test_config.yaml`.

Comment: perfect! thanks 